# D3 Sunburst Chart Not Highlighting Selected Paths

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was extending Sunburst chart of D3. Whenever user clicks on a specific legend then it will highlight all the path associated with that label if that legend is last in the sequence.

Here is working fiddle - http://output.jsbin.com/pezehoveso

**I think my problem is in below function -**

```
function updatePaths(selectedPath) {
    var resultedPath = getSelectedPaths(selectedPath);
    // Fade all the segments.
    // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
    vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(d, i) {
        return (resultedPath);
      })
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }
```

Somehow I'm unable to get selected path highlighted. It's highlighting all the paths. What am I missing?